# Spring 3.1 TransactionManagement with multiple TransactionManagers and Aspectj

Tags: spring, transactions

I have an application with three EntityManagerFactory beans. Each with its own DataSource an TransactionManager (let's call them tx1, tx2 and tx3).

If i use @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) and annotate a service with @Transactional("tx1") i get the following message:

Skipping transactional joinpoint [...] because no transaction manager has been configured

If i remove the AdviceMode.ASPECTJ mode everything works fine.

**Note:**
There is no requirement for JtaTransactions as each DataSource can be access in its own transaction.

Comment: Just for confirmation - you have aspectj weaving either at compile time or runtime enabled right, AdviceMode.ASPECT can be used only if this is done, otherwise you will have to go with the dynamic proxy based transaction management which is working for you.

Comment: Yes, i use compile time weaving